# Number of arrangements in which not all the vowels are together

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many arrangements of the letters of the word ‘BENGALI’ can be made

(i) If the vowels are never together.
I dont want the solution by negation method. I have seen the solution on :http://www.lofoya.com/Aptitude-Questions-And-Answers/Permutation-and-Combination/intro.htm which mentions 4320 but i could not get this answer by non-negation method.

Comment: What about the non-non-negation method?

Comment: @ZevChonoles please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

If the question is asking how many ways can you arrange the letters so that no two vowels are touching, this is how you solve it. You have 5 choose 3 ways of putting 3 vowels around the 4 consonants, which gives 10. The consonants can be permuted 4!=24 ways. The vowels can be permuted 3!=6 ways. You multiply these to get the answer of 1440.

If You want to know the number of arrangements that have exactly two vowels touching, you do something similar. You have 5 choose 2 ways to put the vowel pair and the single vowel around the 4 consonants, which gives 10 also. There are 2!=2 ways to choose which of those vowel spots has the vowel pair. There are 3!=6 ways to permute the vowels, 4!=24 ways to permute the consonants. You multiply these, and get 2880.

If you add these two cases together, you get 4320 ways in which not all 3 vowels are together.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean no two vowels are together, or not all three vowels together?

If no two together, then your vowels (marked as $*$), give your word the form  $..*..*..*..$ giving 4 possible regions in which to place your consonants.

There has to be one consonant in each of the middle two sections, and the remaining two can be distributed as you wish.  There are 10 ways of placing the two free consonants into four boxes $\large(\binom{4}{1}$ for both in a single box, $\binom{4}{2}$ for one each in different boxes $\large)$.  Then $3!$ permutations of the vowels, and $4!$ for the consonants.

Comment: If you follow the link, you will discover that the question means that not all three of the vowels are together.